# LockFailed: failed to create /scratch/

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, celery, lockfile

I am running a pyramid server and am trying to load data through celery.  However, celery is does nothing. Its log file says:

`LockFailed: failed to create /scratch/roman-work-1fb53700.7366`

I found advice to change /scratch permissions by:

`sudo chmod 777 /scratch`

But terminal says that /scratch directory does not exist.  Where should /scratch be situated so that I can create it if it really does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find a solution to this problem anywhere, I am leaving the question up.

```
cd /
sudo mkdir scratch
sudo chmod 777 /scratch
```